# how does multiple correction work when comparing timepoints using nlme and emmeans?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I have performed an experiment were i have two groups, one control group and one treatment group. Each group has 8 individuals. Then i measure the response at 5 different timepoints. Then I want to know if the treatment has any effect and if it does when that effect occurs. I use the nlme package for the test and then follow up using the emmeans package to do post-hoc analysis and specifically pairwise testing between the different genotypes at each timepoint. This will result in 5 different tests and I want to have some type of multiple testing correction for that (such as the holm method).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nlme)
library(emmeans)
```

```
set.seed(6987)
my.df <- data.frame(Time = 1:5, subject=paste("S",i, sep=""), Treat=c("con", "con", "con","con", "con"), Respons = rnorm(5,7,1))

for (i in 1:7) {
  bla.df <- data.frame(Time = 1:5, subject=paste("S",(i+1), sep=""), Treat=c("con", "con", "con","con", "con"), Respons = rnorm(5,7,1))
  my.df <- rbind(my.df, bla.df)
}
for (i in 1:8) {
  bla.df <- data.frame(Time = 1:5, subject=paste("S",(i+8), sep=""), Treat=c("treat", "treat", "treat","treat", "treat"), Respons = rnorm(5,7,1))
  my.df <- rbind(my.df, bla.df)
}
my.df
```

[image]

So then i want to see if the treatment has any effect and if that effect happens on any special timepoint
As I will do 5 different tests for the effect I want to use some type of adjustment to the p-values (such as the holm method). But it looks like the result instead becomes 5 separate tests instead as a series of 5 tests. Is there a different way to do it so that the test becomes linked and that correction for multiple testing becomes added?

```
my.df$Time <- factor(my.df$Time)
my.df.lme <- lme(Respons ~ Treat + Time + Treat*Time,
            random = ~1|subject,
            correlation = corAR1(form =~1|subject),
            data=my.df,
            method="REML")

Anova(my.df.lme)


my.df.emm <- emmeans(my.df.lme, ~Treat*Time, adjust = "holm")
my.df.p <- pairs(my.df.emm, simple = "Treat")
my.df.p
```

And this gives this response

```r
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: Respons
             Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
Treat       1.0405  1    0.30771   
Time        0.1214  4    0.99823   
Treat:Time 14.1875  4    0.00672 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


Time = 1:
 contrast    estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 con - treat    0.725 0.483 13  1.500  0.1574 

Time = 2:
 contrast    estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 con - treat    1.539 0.484 13  3.182  0.0072 

Time = 3:
 contrast    estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 con - treat    0.202 0.484 13  0.418  0.6831 

Time = 4:
 contrast    estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 con - treat   -0.932 0.484 13 -1.927  0.0761 

Time = 5:
 contrast    estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 con - treat   -0.252 0.483 13 -0.522  0.6106 

Degrees-of-freedom method: containment
```

Comment: Nice graphics included. Can you add 3-5 lines in the top of the question to give this forum more context as to what the model serves for, and what you want to compare/predict? Now your question start off with 'code'. Thx.

Comment: I have added some more information now. I hope that it makes it clearer.

Comment: Do `summary(my.df.p, by = NULL, adjust = "holm")`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!